# Wrong output while modelling JK FF: output is x

Tags: verilog, flip-flop

I am modelling a JK FLIP Flop using Verilog.  I am getting the output `q` as `x` in all the cases.  I used `case` statement for various jk combinations.  I hardly found any issue with the code.

Design

```
    module jk_ff ( input j, input k, input clk, output q);
    
           reg q;
    
           always @ (posedge clk)
    
                   case ({j,k})
                 2'b00 :  q <= q;
                 2'b01 :  q <= 1'b0;
                 2'b10 :  q <= 1'b1;
                 2'b11 :  q <= ~q;
              endcase
    endmodule
```

test bench

```
    module tb_jk;  
           reg j;  
           reg k;  
           reg clk;  
          
           always #5 clk = ~clk;  
          
           jk_ff    jk0 ( .j(j),  
                          .k(k),  
                          .clk(clk),  
                          .q(q));  
          
           initial begin  
               $dumpfile("test.vcd");
            $dumpvars;
              j <= 0;  
              k <= 0;  
          
              #5 j <= 0;  
                 k <= 1;  
              #20 j <= 1;  
                  k <= 0;  
              #20 j <= 1;  
                  k <= 1;  
              #20 $finish;  
           end  
          
           initial  
              $monitor ("j=%0d k=%0d q=%0d", j, k, q);  
        endmodule
```

logs

```
    vu2swz@PPDP01:~$ iverilog jk_ff.v 
    vu2swz@PPDP01:~$ ./a.out 
    VCD info: dumpfile test.vcd opened for output.
    j=0 k=0 q=x
    j=0 k=1 q=x
    j=1 k=0 q=x
    j=1 k=1 q=x
```

The output is showing only `x` instead of 0 1 and Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I ran your simulation and looked at waveforms, I saw that `clk` was always unknown (`x`).  You declared `clk` as `reg`, which means that it defaults to `x`.  Your assignment (`clk = ~clk`) does not change the value of `clk` because `~clk` evaluates to `~x`, which is still `x`.

You need to initialize `clk` to a known value in your testbench.  For example, change:

```
       reg clk;
```

to:

```
       reg clk = 0;
```

This shows:

```
j=0 k=0 q=x
j=0 k=1 q=x
j=0 k=1 q=0
j=1 k=0 q=0
j=1 k=0 q=1
j=1 k=1 q=1
j=1 k=1 q=0
```

---

There are 2 ways to debug this problem.  As I mentioned, one way is to look at waveforms; you already create the VCD file.  This is the most efficient way.  The `iverilog` site says GTKWave "is the preferred waveform viewer for Icarus Verilog".

Another way is to add the `clk` signal to your `$monitor` statement:

```
          $monitor ("j=%0d k=%0d q=%0d clk=%b", j, k, q, clk);
```

Then you would have seen:

```
j=0 k=0 q=x clk=x
j=0 k=1 q=x clk=x
j=1 k=0 q=x clk=x
j=1 k=1 q=x clk=x
```